# Accessing dictionary in while loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This code is for adding score based on the letters containing in the word given as argument:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
  word = word.lower()
  n=0
  scorer=0
  while n<=len(word):
    scorer = scorer + score[word[n]]
    n+=1
  return scorer
```

ignore any other syntax error that I might have made..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the code is giving error in output

Comment: Please be more specific than "giving error" – *what* error and on which line?

Comment: Just remove = sign :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate directly over the output of `word.lower()`, rather than indices. Also, you can use the `sum` function to compute the sum of all the dictionary lookups.

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum(score[c] for c in word.lower())
```

A less concise version, sticking with the spirit of your original code, would still iterate over `word` directly.

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    scorer = 0
    for c in word.lower():
        scorer = scorer + score[c]  # or scorer += score[c]
    return scorer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However, two style-related things

In python, strings are iterables of characters, so

```
scorer = 0

for letter in word.lower():
    scorer += score[letter]
```

Even, better, you can use a *list comprehension*

```
scorer = sum([score[letter] for letter in word.lower()])
```

Comment: That's not a list comprehension; it's just a generator expression. `sum([score[letter] for letter in word.lower()])` would make use of a list comprehension.

Comment: @chepner: correct, I omitted the brackets while typing.

Comment: There's no reason to use a list comprehension, though. `sum` just needs an iterable, and generator is sufficient (and does not require all the individual scores be computed before summing, saving memory).

Comment: @chepner: I know, but mentioning generator expressions to someone seeing the language for the first time seems a bit too much.

Comment: Why? They're very useful, and not that hard to understand.

Comment: @chepner: because if the OP doesn't know that strings are iterable in python, I think  generator expression are better left for later. my opinion anyway...

Answer (score 0):

`while n<=len(word):` will throw Index out of bounds

you need `while n<len(word)`

The working copy of your existing function

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    word = word.lower()
    n=0
    scorer=0
    while n<len(word):
        scorer += score[word[n]]
        n+=1
    return scorer
```

As others have pointed out a much cleaner approach would be to iterate over the characters of the word rather than indices

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    word = word.lower()
    scorer=0
    for char in word:
        scorer += score[char]
    return scorer
```